# Running threading + queue in a daemon process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-daemon

I have successfully implemented threading + queue in a Python file, **myfile.py**. Now I want this file to run as a daemon because when all the threads have completed their tasks, I want to re-populate the queue and have the threads work on the new task. I am trying out some code here, but the program is not responding correctly:

```
# myfile.py

threadList = list()
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    threadName = "T" + str(i)
    threadList.append(threadName)

#create queue
myQueue = Queue.Queue();

# create thread objects
threads = list()
for threadName in threadList:
    thread = WorkerThread(threadName, myQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

def hello():    
    while True:
        logger.debug("true")
        if myQueue.empty():
            logger.debug("empty")
        else:
            logger.debug("not empty")

def run():
    daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext(files_preserve=[handler.stream],
                                          stdout = open("./stdout.log","wb"),
                                          stderr = open("./stderr.log","wb"))
    with daemon_context:
        hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When the script is executed, it prints "true" and stop there. It doesn't log "empty" or "not empty". There are no errors shown in the terminal, and in stderr.log. However, if i remove the condition check for `myQueue.empty()`, the daemon will continue to print "true". Why is queue not working in a daemon?

Comment: have you stepped through a debugger?  If so, break on `logger.debug("true")` and see the state.  Take the next step and then see what myQueue.empty() is evaluating as -- I've seen instances where standard lib code will bomb out, silently fail, and never evaluate, thus never getting to your conditional eval.  Better yet, for a 'belt-and-suspenders' approach, wrap your `if` block in a `try/except` and see if the except is thrown.  This isn't going to solve your problem, but it'll help you debug what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're seeing this strange behavior because you're running a bunch of your code prior to daemonizing, which is doing an `os.fork()` internally. That's leaving you in a weird state where some of your code started in one process, but then you fork (meaning you get a new process) and start trying to use those objects that you created prior to the fork, which won't work properly. All your running threads will get killed, for example. You need to move *all* your code inside of the `with daemon_context` block for things to start working.

I would be careful with this, though. You're rapidly writing quite a bit to disk with that `while True` loop.

Comment: Just to amplify about what kind of weird state the OP might be ending up in: Their code is most likely hanging on `myQueue.empty()` because a worker thread was holding the queue's mutex when the process forked; the main thread can never acquire the lock in that case.